# Emacs Error in dotspacemacs-mode-line-unicode-symbols

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

Not sure what this means?

```
 error(s) at startup! Spacemacs may not be able to operate properly.
--> deleting dockerfile-mode... [5/5]
Error in dotspacemacs/user-config: Wrong number of arguments: (lambda (mode unicode &optional ascii) "Dimi$
`dotspacemacs-mode-line-unicode-symbols'.
If ASCII si not provided then UNICODE is used instead." (list (quote add-to-list) (quote (quote spacemacs-$
```

cause I don't even have a user-config directory

Comment: Meant is the part starting with `(defun dotspacemacs/user-init ()` in your `~/.spacemacs` file. I think it would be helpful if you paste the contents from there.

Comment: I pushed it to https://github.com/drgeb/spacemacs